# How to prevent .net 4 handling 404 on IIS6

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-6, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

I have what seems to be the exact opposite of everyone else's problem! I am hosting a .Net4 site on IIS6, and while I want IIS to handle 404 errors (where I can configure it to send the error to an aspx page), it seems like .Net4 gets in the way by issuing a 302 redirect for the default page (which doesn't exist either) before I can get on with handling the 404 properly.

Basically, if I goto `http://mysite/testProduct`, `.net4` issues a `302` for `http://mysite/testProduct/default.aspx`, which then goes on and gets handled by my error handling setup in IIS6 which is to redirect 404s to `/404.aspx`, which detects the product name, looks up an ID and does a Server.Transfer.

How can I stop .Net getting in the way? It's doubling the overhead of a page request, and will cause my products to get indexed with `/default.aspx` after them which I do not want.

AHA, Ben

EDIT: if I turn off CustomErrors in the web.config, .Net is still handling the error and not letting it pass to IIS at all - I see a 404 error page that is generated by `.Net`. So I get a `302` then a `404`...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem in the end - this was for an implementation of nopCommerce, which comes with UrlReWriter installed out of the box - it was this component that was causing the behaviour noted above...